# Python BeautifulSoup4 get range of table rows

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML table containing 6 table rows:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<td><p>1</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>2</th>
<td><p>2</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>3</th>
<td><p>3</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>4</th>
<td><p>4</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>5</th>
<td><p>5</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>6</th>
<td><p>6</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**My goal here is to extract only the first 5 rows.**

How can i code it in python such that BeautifulSoup breaks after getting the first 5 rows?

Comment: have you tried it? or are you just punting it to us lol. let us see what you've tried so far. maybe the code to get all 6 and we will help you out to just get 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `limit` kwarg in `findAll` to grab only the first `n` elements

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
trs = soup.find('table').findAll('tr', limit=5)
```

Comment: Hi Wondercricket. Thank you! Seems like i have not read enough of the BeautifulSoup documentation...